# Making a stored procedure return 5 little data from three different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble with stored procedure here and I'm not sure what to do or how to approach this. I'm sure there's a genius out here that can help me out! :D

[image]

I want my stored procedure to return Anuncio's idAnuncio, titulo, precio, descripcion, and by using it's foreign keys return Categoria's descripcion and Imagenes's imagen.

But here's the catch, I need to send a idCategoria (int) variable from my app so the stored procedure can go: "*Ah, you want to see all the items that have category 1, here's ya go.*" and it return a  or array with everything inside.

Please help! I'm completely lost and I just need a working example to figure out the rest.

Thanks guys! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROC DoStuff
   @Parameter int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    Categoria C
    JOIN
    Anuncio A ON C.idCategoria = A.idCategoria
    JOIN
    Imagenes I ON A.idImagen = I.idImagen 
WHERE
    C.idCategoria = @Parameter;
GO
```

Comment: It does now... It showed how to use a parameter though which is arguably what OP wanted...

Comment: I think your solution will work but I get an error that Anuncio is an invalid object name. I don't get that error with Categoria, why would this happen on Anuncio? Check http://bit.ly/3Dfjlu for the problem. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @CategoriaID INT
SET @CategoriaID = 1

SELECT a.idAnuncio,
       a.titulo,
       a.precio,
       a.descripcion,
       c.descripcion,
       i.imagen
FROM  bo.Anuncio a
    INNER JOIN dbo.Categoria c
        ON a.idCategoria = c.idCategoria
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Imagenes i
        ON a.idImagen = i.idImagen
WHERE a.idCategoria = @CategoriaID
```

It's a query but you should be able to turn it into an SP easy enough.  There might be a couple of spelling mistakes but it should get you started.